# ExoPlayer при проигрывании аудио файла добавляется помехи

Tags: android, аудио, exoplayer

При проигрывании файла в конце добавляется дополнительный звук (жужжания). Не могу понять, откуда это приходит. Если файл проигрывать на компе, доп. звука нет. Пробовал через MediaPlayer, все ок, но мне именно ExoPlayer надо.
Не могу просто код выложить, так как надо запускать проект, что б понять проблему
Создал демо проект, на котором можно быстро посмотреть.
Ссылка на репозиторий - https://github.com/toktogul/exoplayer-demo

Comment: Исправил, просто обновил exoplayer до последней версии